# A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host

Tags: .net, wcf, networking, network-programming, wcf-client

One customer reported this error at my WCF client connecting to our server service.

"Message: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host
                Type   : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException"

From this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx i see:

WSAEHOSTUNREACH
10065
No route to host.
A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host. See WSAENETUNREACH.

WSAENETUNREACH
10051
Network is unreachable.
A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. This usually means the local software knows no route to reach the remote host.

Is this a network error on customer network? 
Is it something we can advise customer to do?

WCF Client was able to connect to the server service before and seems that problem disappeared after reboot of machine (or maybe network problem was fixed in the meantime).

Thank you

Adriana

Comment: Yes, network error or glitch on the one machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error indicates that the network was not connected or not configured correctly. It is definitely an error on the client machine, not your server.

There isn't much you can do to "solve" the problem. Pretty much all you can do is upgrade the client's network drivers and check for connection problems (maybe they're barely within wireless range, or the Ethernet cable is missing its locking tab).

Comment: I am able to connect to internet but i am getting this error while sending email in c# code. i am having windows 10 what should i do ?

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla: I don't know. I recommend reducing the code to a reproducible example and posting your own question.

Comment: Okay I will do it.

Comment: I found that this error occurs in the system during development. When you open local site being connected to one network. Then you change the network, e.g. disconnect from VPN, and try to open local site again => you get this error.  All you need is just to connect to the previous network, i.e. restore network environment. Or reboot the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can help your customers or FAEs to develop an SOP for identifying connectivity issues.  Say, pinging the server IP from client machine, do an ipconfig and see if the machine's network adapter is up or not.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was due to an internet connection issue while executing a python script.